# C# Performance penalty for Int32 literals to floats

Tags: c#, .net, performance, compiler-construction

In c#, you can define a number literal as either int or double

```
    Double var1 = 56.1;
    int var2 = 51;
```

These are the default types the literals are assigned. However, the game engine I'm working on uses floats for position, rotation, etc. When the float is assigned a literal double, ie, `float varFloat = 75.4;` the compiler throws an error saying that the double literal needs to be a float, which is correct. So one needs to turn the double literal into a float ie. `float varFloat = 75.4f;`. However, when given an int literal, the int is implicitly converted to a float. Ie,

```
    float varFloat = 44; // This is fine.
```

My question is is the compiler smart enough to realize that 44 should be a float literal? If not, that means that every time the literal is accessed, it's also performing a conversion. In most cases, this really doesn't matter. But with high performance code, it could potentially become an issue (even if it's a minor one) if ints are used all over the place instead of floats. There is no way as far as I know to change these literals into floats without going through lines of source code which really isn't time well spent at all.

So, does the compiler convert the int literal into a float literal? If not, what can be done about this waste of processing power other then trying to avoid it?

Comment: "Waste in processing power" is a pretty bold statement regarding a language construct like literals. It would be worth your time to read through the C# [Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx) to get a feel for how C# actually works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is yes.  It is smart enough to know that.

This is the disassembled IL (courtesy of [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)) of a simple program which has such an assignment.  As you can see [from the ldc.r4 instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_r4.aspx), there is no conversion taking place:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Main (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 8 (0x8)
    .maxstack 1
    .entrypoint
    .locals init (
        [0] float32 x
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldc.r4 44
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Comment: [I wouldn't call "per the standard" being terribly smart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y5b434w4.aspx). Perhaps "handy".

Comment: How about "the standard is smart enough"?  :)

Answer (score 3):

float is "smaller" than double

when you try to convert float to double you may lose precision

see this:[C: convert double to float, preserving decimal point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498192/c-convert-double-to-float-preserving-decimal-point-precision)

same is true about C#

when you write 
float x = 5;
the compiler will in compile time will convert this to 
float x = 5.0;

no performance problems

Comment: +1 for a plausible explanation of _why_ it converts 5.0 but not 5.1.

Comment: It will preserve magnitude but not necessarily precision.

Comment: This wasn't a question about converting doubles to floats, but if there is a performance impact about assigning integer literals to floats. Still, useful information for others.