# Precision loss from float to double, and from double to float?

Tags: c++, c, floating-accuracy

```
float fv = orginal_value;  // original_value may be any float value
...
double dv = (double)fv;
...
fv = (float)dv;
```

SHOULD fv be equal to original_value exactly? Any precision may be lost?

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498192/c-convert-double-to-float-preserving-decimal-point-precision

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think it is different. the question backend is: I want to store a float(32bit) value to double(64bit) for simplicity, but after some procedure, restore the original float value from the double stored value. in the issue you mentioned, I only see it mentioned to convert from double to float)

Comment: What is the type of `original_value` ?

Comment: Are you asking for C or C++?

Comment: For this question, any difference between C and C++?

Comment: @ravin.wang: I'm slightly thrown off by your use of _SHOULD_. are you asking whether or not a double to float demotion is without risks in general, or only in specific cases?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am writing a general function, all float and double values are stored in a double field, but when getting it in some other place, I'd like to restore its original value.

Comment: Original value != original type... but if you're going to operate on a value, demoting to float from double is a bad idea

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> SHOULD fv be equal to original_value exactly? Any precision may be
>   lost?

Yes, if the value of `dv` did not change in between.

From section **Conversion 6.3.1.5 Real Floating types** in C99 specs:

> 1. When a float is promoted to double or long double, or a double is
>      promoted to long double, **its value is unchanged**.
> 2. When a double is
>      demoted to float, a long double is demoted to double or float, or a
>      value being represented in greater precision and range than required
>      by its semantic type (see 6.3.1.8) is explicitly converted to its
>      semantic type, **if the value being converted can be represented exactly**
>      in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value being converted is in
>      the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented
>      exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower
>      representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. If
>      the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be
>      represented, the behavior is undefined

For C++, from section **4.6** aka **conv.fpprom** (draft used: [n337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) and I believe similar lines are available in final specs)

> A prvalue of type float can be converted to a prvalue of type double.
>   **The value is unchanged**. This conversion is called floating point
>   promotion.

And section **4.8** aka **conv.double**

> A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   another floating point type. **If the source value can be exactly
>   represented in the destination type**, the result of the conversion is
>   that exact representation. If the source value is between two adjacent
>   destination values, the result of the conversion is an
>   implementation-defined choice of either of those values. Otherwise,
>   the behavior is undefined.  The conversions allowed as floating point
>   promotions are excluded from the set of floating point conversions

So the values should be equal exactly.

Comment: It's important to note that, what the OP added as  `...` lines in the snippet should ***not*** change the value of `dv`, if it does, loss of precision or even UB might follow

Comment: Initial "SHOULD fv be equal to original_value exactly? Any precision may be lost?" are 2 questions and answer "Yes" only applies to the first one - It appears you want "no" to the 2nd question.  Suggest small edit to clarify.