# bson-append_double with double precision

Tags: bson, mongo-c-driver

I got a problem with function bson_append_double below:

```
dvalue = 0.01;
bson_append_double(pbson, field_name, -1,(double)dvalue);
```

but the result i got is annoying long: 0.0099999997764825820923
Did anyone faced this problem before, please help me.
Thanks and Regards

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Same as input 0.01. Can it be?

Answer (score 0):

this is simply a float-to-double conversion.  If you don't want to lose the precision, you'll need to declare the variable as a double in the first place.

somewhere in your code you have a line

```
float dvalue;
```

if you are able to promote to type double you should consider changing the declaration to:

```
double dvalue;
```

here is a previous question on loss of precision in conversions.

[Precision loss from float to double, and from double to float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840173/precision-loss-from-float-to-double-and-from-double-to-float?noredirect=1&lq=1)